# Open iOS Settings App (top level - not deep link into the App Settings page) - iOS 12/13

Tags: ios, settings, preferences

I'm working on a iOS App which interacts with different hardware.  We access and configure these devices using a "Soft AP" work flow (ie hotspot)

Our preference is to use `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` to automate the process for the user and in most cases this works fine.

However, in those edge cases where it doesn't (ie iOS 13+ and location services) we'd like to make the workflow as simple for the user as possible.

Currently we have a nice list of steps that the user needs to take:

- Press/swipe home
- Open Settings
- Navigate to WiFi settings
- Find and tap the specified WiFi SSID
- Return to the App

It's really not pleasant at all.

I'm aware that there is not official way to open the WiFi settings and I can live with that, but recently I was mucking around with the Wyze App and pairing one of their light bulbs and noted that they have manual workflow which opens the top level Settings page - NOT the App's settings.  *(nb: The Wyze App also has "app settings")*

So, after some more reading, I find that `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` will open the App's specific settings page, which is cool and everything, but this is not what I need.  I'd be really awesome if it was "officially" possible to launch the iOS Settings App and NOT have it open the App's settings, but just land on the top level page.

I know if the App has no settings, this is the behaviour I will get, but our App does (and I can't be changed)

I don't want to/can't use URL schemes like `prefs:root` unless it can be guaranteed not to be rejected by Apple!

And, yes, I look at a lot of different blogs and questions on the subject, including [A Comprehensive Guide to All 120+ Settings URLs Supported by iOS and iPadOS 13.1](https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/) - but I'd like to not have the App rejected

Comment: There is no official way to open settings other than your own app's settings.  Waze might have snuck by the review process.  Prefs:root is pretty much guaranteed to be rejected by Apple.

Comment: ☹️ Yeah, this is pretty much what I was expecting, but I thought it worth while checking if anyone else might know of something I'm missing - it's hard to filter the available information